# asp:RequiredFieldValidator triggers on unrelated update

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am building an ASP.Net web site on framework 4.0 and VB.Net.

I am using an asp:GridView with update and delete functionality and when I use the update of the grid view, unrelated RequiredFieldValidators on the page trigger and prevent the update.

Is there a way to prevent them from triggering at this point?